# Making a button via CSS, but instead get two bars on top

Tags: html, css, button, padding

I am trying to create a button for my link which has the name on the button
and allows the user to click on it and go to the link.

Also I'm not sure why but my link "click-able range" seems to be extended.

Here is the Code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">

<a href="http://www.medium.com/" target="Medium"><div id="link">My Favorite Website</div></a>

    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container {
width:960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 30px 0px;
}

a {
padding: 7px 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-size: 80px 60px;
background-color: green;
text-decoration: none;
}

#link {
padding: 7px;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: do not wrap div inside <a> for just a simple text, use a span instead :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what do you mean with "my 'ink "click-able range' seems to be extended" and why would that be a problem?

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for the suggestion! As you can see I'm just starting front-end web development so I'm just getting used to it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @RoToRa Hi! I meant to say that whenever the link "My favorite website" seemed to be clickable anywhere in the line, meaning I didn't even really have to hover over the actual text itself. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is inline element so you need to make it block or inline-block to add your styles so:

**CSS**

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Hopefully I'll learn more about inline vs block!

Answer (score 1):

Having a block element within an inline one is causing your problems.

By default, anchors are displayed `inline`. You need to display it a little differently, as `inline-block`:

```
a {
    padding: 7px 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/PgqX6/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove div tag into a tag..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1162/)

```
<div id="container">

<a href="http://www.medium.com/" target="Medium">My Favorite Website</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this to #link in css

```
appearance:button;
-moz-appearance:button; 
-webkit-appearance:button;
```

Answer (score 0):

is an inline element. To make it behave like a block level element, you need to define its display property in CSS.

a {display:block;} or a {display:inline-block;}

and your link "click-able range" seems to be extended, because you are using a , which is a block level element, inside your  tag.

Block level elements take the entire width of its container.

You need to redefine its bevavior.

## link{display:inline-block;} or #link{display:inline;}